# Something is wrong filling array

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I have the following ajax call:

```
 $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '../ws_BQS.asmx/ResultadosDimensionalByDate',
    data: '{"fecha":"' + fecha + '"}',
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    timeout: 600000,
    error: function (xhr) {

    },
    success: function (data) {
        var t = data.d;
        var split;
        var datos = t.split(",");

        //Thickness
        for (var i = 0; i < datos.length; i++) {
            array1.push(datos[i]);
            i++;
            i++;
            i++;
            //alert(array1);
        }
        //Width
        for (var w = 0; w < datos.length; w++) {
            w++;
            //array2.push(datos[w]);
            w++;
            w++;
        }
        alert(array1);

        chart(array1);
    }
});
```

Alert message is (1,5,9,14,18) that's what I expect, but the problem is that my chart function is not doing what I want, here is the code:

```
function chart(arreglo) {


$('#Grafica').highcharts({
    chart: {
        type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Inspeccion Dimensional'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Pieza 1', 'Pieza 2', 'Pieza 3', 'Pieza 4', 'Pieza 5']
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Resultados'
        }
    },
    legend: {
        reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Thickness',
        data: arreglo
    }, {
        name: 'Width',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Length',
        data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
    }, {
        name: 'Diameter',
        data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
    }]
});

alert(arreglo);
}
```

My alert message is the same from my ajax call so that's ok, the problem is when I use my var `arreglo` in `series` option, I dont get any error message, just it seems that `arreglo it's empty`, I'm trying to solve this and I found that could be an issue from `array1.push(datos[i]);` because if I do `array1.push(values manually)` it works, how can I solve this?

**UPDATE**

Here is a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvf6vcn5/2/) to see my problem.

**UPDATE #2**

These are the ways that I get my data:

```
data: console.log = 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21

var datos = t.split(",");
console.log(datos) = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21"]

for loop
console.log(array1) = ["1", "5", "9", "14", "18"]

chart function
console.log(arreglo) = ["1", "5", "9", "14", "18"]
```

With this I can see that it's wrong receiving data with "", so how can I change this?

Comment: Just FYI, you can do `i+=3` instead of having `i++` 3 imes

Comment: Where's `array1` defined?

Comment: @Rajesh That's right! I was testing how much numbers I have to add.

Comment: @Utkanos it's a global variable `var array1 = new Array();`

Comment: Can you paste data variable? How does it look?

Comment: @morganfree Ready!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array must contain numbers, instead it contains strings which is why the series looks like it does not have any data.

Parse strings to number and it works as expected.

```
data: arreglo.map(function (value) {
    return Number(value);
  })
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/nvf6vcn5/4/